# Why pthread_key need destructor?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, destructor

I am reading [APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/apue3e.html) the chapter about thread specific data. I see following code snipit:

```
void destructor(void *);
pthread_key_t key;
pthread_once_t init_done = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

void thread_init(void){
    err = pthread_key_create(&key, destructor);
}
int threadfunc(void *arg){
    pthread_once(&init_done, thread_init);
//...
}
```

I have several questions:

1. I don't understand how does `key` initialize
2. Why does this key need destructor? And what does this destructor do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: `pthread_once` uses a flag to make sure that a function is called one time only. In this case that function is `thread_init`, which uses a pointer to `key` to initialize it, and a pointer to the `destructor` function to clean it up. That is useful to avoid memory leaks or open files or anything that might be opened or allocated because threads can exit for many reasons, such as error conditions. A destructor function makes it easier to handle.

Comment: @ZanLynx, but in this example destructor function does nothing. Am I right?

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ We don't know because all that code shows is a declaration, not any definition of the function. As is, it would compile but fail to link.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand how does `key` initialize

`key` is used to identify a slot in thread-specific storage. `pthread_key_create` stores the slot number in `key`.

> Why does this key need destructor? And what does this destructor do?

See [`pthread_key_create`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_key_create.html):

> An optional destructor function may be associated with each key value. At thread exit, if a key value has a non-NULL destructor pointer, and the thread has a non-NULL value associated with that key, the value of the key is set to NULL, and then the function pointed to is called with the previously associated value as its sole argument. The order of destructor calls is unspecified if more than one destructor exists for a thread when it exits.